# How to format a vps.

Tags: linux, centos, vps

I have a VPS bought from digital ocean, and I would like to have it formatted to its default state. However, Digital Ocean provides the option to only "destory" the VPS. Meaning, I would even loos the IP and start a new vps.

I would like to know, if `rm -rf /` is suited for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `rm -rf /` is not the solution.  How do you plan on reinstalling the OS if you do that?

From the [Digital Ocean FAQ](https://www.digitalocean.com/help/technical/product/):

> **How do I start over with a fresh installation?**
>
> To restart your droplet with a different operating system, or perform
>   a fresh installation of your current one, follow these easy steps:
>
> 1. Login to the control panel, navigate to your list of droplets, and
>      select the one you wish to destroy or re-deploy.
> 2. Click "Destroy" then
>      "Rebuild" and choose the appropriate operating system from the "Select
>      an Image" menu.
> 3. Finally, click the blue "Rebuild From Image" button.
>
> IMPORTANT: All data on your droplet will be destroyed when it is
>   rebuilt. Remember to backup your data or take snapshots of your work
>   in order to preserve that image.
>
> Your IP will be preserved.